# How to flatten disorganised dictionaries into list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I attempted to flatten a disorganized dictionary (that in turn was taken from a json file) to ease extracting info. Below is an example of how the dictionary is structured and my attempt at flattening it:

```
data = {'horse':{'speed':{"walk": 40, "run":50}}, 'dog':{'run':30}, 'human':{'gait':{'normal':{'run': 25, 'walk': 30}}}}

flat_dict = []
for items in list(data.items()):
    flat_list = []
    flat_list.append(items[0])
    try:
        for item in list(items[1].items())[0]:
            if type(item) is not dict: 
                flat_list.append(item)
            else:
                flat_list.append(list(item.keys())[0])
                flat_list.append(list(item.values())[0])
    except:
        flat_list.append(items[0])
    flat_dict.append(flat_list)

print(flat_dict)
```

However the above code does not flatten the entire dictionary and some information is lost, here's the output of the above code:

```
[['horse', 'speed', 'walk', 40], ['dog', 'run', 30], ['human', 'gait', 'normal', {'run': 25, 'walk': 30}]]
```

What I wanted was:

```
[['horse', 'speed', 'walk', 40, 'run', 50], ['dog', 'run', 30], ['human', 'gait', 'normal', 'run', 25, 'walk', 30]]
```

What do I do?

Comment: Can you show your expected result?

Comment: Why do you need to put it into a list? It's already easy to extract info from a dictionary. Google python dictionaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a recursive approach with a list comprehension:

```
 def gen(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield k
            yield from gen(v)
    else:
        yield d 

[[k, *gen(v)] for k, v in data.items()]
```

**output:**

```
 [['horse', 'speed', 'walk', 40, 'run', 50],
 ['dog', 'run', 30],
 ['human', 'gait', 'normal', 'run', 25, 'walk', 30]]
```

Comment: what does a "*" do in front of a function name like you have given "*gen(v)"?

Comment: you can read more about  `*` iterable unpacking operator in [PEP448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

Comment: i read it, but didnt find any answer to what you have done in your answer

Comment: @Sankar Short answer : will put all the elements generated by function `gen` în the list, it is better?

Answer (score 1):

As you don't know the structure inside the `dict` you cannot use simple loops to handle each case, you need to use recursion, I'd suggest an utility method to flatten whatever structure recursivly, then make use it to make arrays of `[key, flatten(values)]`

```
def flatten(values) -> list:
    if isinstance(values, list):
        return [v for value in values for v in flatten(value)]
    if isinstance(values, dict):
        return [*values.keys(), *flatten(list(values.values()))]
    return [values]


def flatten_dict(values: dict) -> list:
    return [[key, *flatten(value)] for key, value in values.items()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ['foo']
    print(flatten('foo'))

    # ['foo', 'bar', 'uio', 1, 2, 3, 'k1', 'k2', 'v1', 'kk1', '9', 5, 9, 8, 7]
    print(flatten(['foo', ['bar', 'uio', [1, 2, 3]], {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': {'kk1': ['9', 5, 9, 8, 7, ]}}]))

    data = {'horse': {'speed': {"walk": 40, "run": 50}}, 'dog': {'run': 30},
            'human': {'gait': {'normal': {'run': 25, 'walk': 30}}}}

    # [['horse', 'speed', 'walk', 'run', 40, 50], ['dog', 'run', 30], ['human', 'gait', 'normal', 'run', 'walk', 25, 30]]
    print(flatten_dict(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered as asked:

```
data = {
    'horse': {
        'speed': {
            "walk": 40, "run": 50}},
    'dog': {
        'run': 30},
    'human': {
        'gait': {
            'normal': {
                'run': 25, 'walk': 30}}}}


def my_flatten(ddict, mylist):
    for k, v in ddict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            mylist.append(k)
            my_flatten(v, mylist)
        else:
            mylist.extend([k, v])
    return mylist


flist = [my_flatten(v, [k]) for k, v in data.items()]
print(flist)
```